# Collapse Highcharts Organization Chart

Tags: highcharts, organization

I'm using Highcharts to create organization charts as in provided example : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/7rb6esqt/

Is it possible to add a "collapse" feature as in the Google organization chart ? In the following example https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/kb2gted4 when you double clic on "Mike" or "Jim" cell, it collapse all the cells above. I need to reproduce an equivalent mode with Highcharts, do you have an idea to do that ? (in Google API, the collapse mode is enabled via

```
    allowCollapse:true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in functionality in Highcharts, but you can add it by using click event and show/hide methods. Example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        const operateChildren = (point, operation) => {
                            point.linksFrom.forEach(link => {
                                link.graphic[operation]();
                                link.toNode.graphic[operation]();

                                operateChildren(link.toNode, operation);
                            });
                        };

                        if (this.linksFrom && this.linksFrom[0]) {
                            if (this.linksFrom[0].graphic.visibility === 'hidden') {
                                operateChildren(this, 'show');
                            } else {
                                operateChildren(this, 'hide');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(tooltip) {
            if (this.point.graphic.visibility !== 'hidden') {
                return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dp03gq6a/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#show

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

Comment: Thanks a lot for this feature. I have 2 additional requests about this feature : in the following example, is it possible to "redraw" the chart once a node is fold/unfold (to optimise the space left and realign the nodes) ? Other stuff : is it possible to highlight from the node to the high level parent when the mouse is hover a node ? I saw that in highchart.css file something like that is made but its only for the previous parent and the child. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, Could you create a new SO question for that? I think that it will be better for the others to separate these two threads.